# How to delete this indelible directory?

Tags: files, directory, nfs, rm

I untarred a corrupt tar file, and managed to end up with some directory
that I can not delete,
If I try to delete it, it seems like  it can not be found, but `ls` shows it's present, both with bash and with python I get similar behaviour, except right after I try to delete it with `rm -rf`,  `ls` complains it can't find it, then it lists it (see below after `rm -rf`). The `find` command shows the file is present, 
but still I can't think of a way to delete it.
Here are my attempts:

Here you see both `ls` and `find` agree we have a directory,

```
rl]$ ls
mikeaâ??cnt
rl]$ find -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -print0  
./mikeaâcnt
```

But I can't delete it:

```
rl]$ find -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -print0 |  xargs -0 rm -f -v 
rm: cannot remove `./mikeaâ\302\201\302\204cnt': Is a directory
rl]$ ls
mikeaâ??cnt
```

I can `cd` to it though and it's empty:

```
rl]$ cd mikeaâ^Á^Äcnt/
mikeaâ^Á^Äcnt]$ ls
mikeaâ^Á^Äcnt]$ pwd
.../rl/mikeaâcnt


mikeaâ^Á^Äcnt]$ cd ../
rl]$ ls
mikeaâ??cnt
```

see below that is not a simple file but a directory, plus `ls` behaves funny after the `rm -rf`  it says it can't find the file then lists it straight after:

```
rl]$ rm mikeaâ^Á^Äcnt/
rm: cannot remove `mikeaâ\302\201\302\204cnt/': Is a directory
rl]$ rm -rf  mikeaâ^Á^Äcnt/
rl]$ ls
ls: cannot access mikeaâcnt: No such file or directory
mikeaâ??cnt
rl]$
```

So this is the attempt with python, the file is found, but the name is not
usable as a name that can be deleted:

```
rl]$ python 
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 10 2013, 22:48:45) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import shutil
>>> os.listdir('.')
['mikea\xc3\xa2\xc2\x81\xc2\x84cnt']
>>> shutil.rmtree(os.listdir('.')[0] )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/shutil.py", line 204, in rmtree
    onerror(os.listdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/shutil.py", line 202, in rmtree
    names = os.listdir(path)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mikea\xc3\xa2\xc2\x81\xc2\x84cnt'
```

even when I use tab completion the name it picks up is no usable:

```
rl]$ rm -rf mikeaâ^Á^Äcnt 
rl]$ ls
ls: cannot access mikeaâcnt: No such file or directory
mikeaâ??cnt
```

using the name that python shows with  bash I get this:

```
rl]$ rm -rf "mikea\xc3\xa2\xc2\x81\xc2\x84cnt"
rl]$ ls
ls: cannot access mikeaâcnt: No such file or directory
mikeaâ??cnt
```

Is there anything I can do to get rid of this corrupt dir?
The underlying filesystem (NFS) seems functional and no other problems are reported, and I have had no such problems until the corrupt tar file.

EDIT:
Here is using `find`'s own `-exec` option to call `rm`

```
rl]$ find -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -exec rm -f {} \;
find: `./mikeaâ\302\201\302\204cnt': No such file or directory
rl]$ ls
ls: cannot access mikeaâcnt: No such file or directory
mikeaâ??cnt
rl]$
```

but the file is still there, (`ls` complains it can't find it, but then shows it anyway)

2nd EDIT:

```
rl]$ find -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -exec rm -rf {} \;
find: `./mikeaâ\302\201\302\204cnt': No such file or directory
rl]$ ls
ls: cannot access mikeaâcnt: No such file or directory
mikeaâ??cnt
```

The behaviour is still unchanged, the file still present

3rd EDIT:

```
rl]$ ls
mikeaâ??cnt
rl]$ find -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -exec rm -rf {} + 
rl]$ ls
ls: cannot access mikeaâcnt: No such file or directory
mikeaâ??cnt
```

There seems to be more to the name than `mikeaâcnt` from looking at the output of the python attempt  `mikea\xc3\xa2\xc2\x81\xc2\x84cnt`, and this screenshot:

[image: ls output]

4th EDIT:
This is the attempt with a wild card:

```
rl]$ echo * 
mikeaâcnt
rl]$ echo mike* 
mikeaâcnt
rl]$ rm -rf mike*
rl]$ ls
ls: cannot access mikeaâcnt: No such file or directory
mikeaâ??cnt
```

and my locale:

```
rl]$  locale
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

5th Edit:

```
rl]$ ls -i 
ls: cannot access mikeaâcnt: No such file or directory
? mikeaâ??cnt
```

but also the behaviour has changed, now `ls` and `cd`  do this:

```
rl]$ ls
ls: cannot access mikeaâcnt: No such file or directory
mikeaâ??cnt
rl]$ cd mikeaâ^Á^Äcnt 
mikeaâcnt: No such file or directory.
```

This has happened after the attempts to delete, I'm thinking that it might be NFS issues as suggested in one of the answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147381/79125) by vinc17.

6th EDIT:
This is the output of `lsof` and `ls -a`

<strike>rl]$ /usr/sbin/lsof mikeaâ^Á^Äcnt
    lsof: status error on mikeaâ\xc2\x81\xc2\x84cnt: No such file or directory</strike>

above is wrong, here is the correct `lsof` invocation:(rl is the parent directory)

```
rl]$ /usr/sbin/lsof | grep mike | grep rl 
tcsh      11926   mike  cwd       DIR   0,33     4096 19569249 /home/mike/mish/rl
lsof      14733   mike  cwd       DIR   0,33     4096 19569249 /home/mike/mish/rl
grep      14734   mike  cwd       DIR   0,33     4096 19569249 /home/mike/mish/rl
grep      14735   mike  cwd       DIR   0,33     4096 19569249 /home/mike/mish/rl
lsof      14736   mike  cwd       DIR   0,33     4096 19569249 /home/mike/mish/rl
rl]$ 

rl]$ ls -a
ls: cannot access mikeaâcnt: No such file or directory
.  ..  mikeaâ??cnt
```

7th Edit:
move won't work, (I tried it before all this, but I did not save the output), but it has the same problem as `ls` and `rm`  with the file.

8th EDIT: 
this is using the hex chars as suggested:

```
 rl]$ ls --show-control-chars | xxd
0000000: 6d69 6b65 61c3 a2c2 81c2 8463 6e74 0a    mikea......cnt.
rl]$ rmdir $'mikea\6d69\6b65\61c3\a2c2\81c2\8463\6e74\0acnt' 
rmdir: failed to remove `mikea\006d69\006b651c3\a2c2\\81c2\\8463\006e74': No such file or directory
rl]$ ls
ls: cannot access mikeaâcnt: No such file or directory
mikeaâ??cnt
rl]$
```

9th Edit:
for  the `stat` command:

```
 rl]$ stat  mikeaâ^Á^Äcnt 
stat: cannot stat `mikeaâ\302\201\302\204cnt': No such file or directory
 rl]$
```

Its seems even more likely from all the output, there is a bug or other NFS misbehaviour as suggested in the comments.

Edit 10: 
This is strace output in a gist since its so large,
its the output or these two commands:

```
strace -xx rmdir ./* | grep -e '-1 E'`
strace -xx -e trace=file ls -li`
```

https://gist.github.com/mikeatm/e07fa600747a4285e460

Edit 11:
So before the above  `rmdir` I noticed that I could `cd` into the directory, 
but after the `rmdir` I could not `cd` again, similar to yesterday. The `.` and `..`  files were present:

```
rl]$ ls
mikeaâ??cnt
rl]$ cd mikeaâ^Á^Äcnt/
mikeaâ^Á^Äcnt]$ ls
mikeaâ^Á^Äcnt]$ ls  -a
.  ..
mikeaâ^Á^Äcnt]$ cd ../
```

Final Edit:
I saw a local admin over this and it was dealt with by logging on to the server itself and deleting from there. The explanation from them is that it could be a problem with character sets in the name being inappropriate.

Comment: Is there a reason you're piping `find`'s output to a different command instead of just using it's `exec` option?

Comment: @HalosGhost there was no reason, see edit for added information on your question

Comment: You don't want the `-f` option for `rm`. You want the `-r` option. Having both might be helpful, but if it's a directory, you need the `-r` flag.

Comment: Can you try this once `rm -rf mikea*`.

Comment: What is the output of `locale`? The fact that your terminal is spitting out nonsense characters is a signal that there may be an issue with your locale.

Comment: @Learn please see the 4th edit,

Comment: @HalosGhost i added info on the locale

Comment: perhaps this is system-specific, but I've always seen `LANG` set to `en_US.UTF-8`, not `en_US.utf8`. How did you set your locale?

Comment: @mike-m: Can you please try this command `rm -r mikeaâ\?\?cnt/`. I guess you need to escape the question mark (?).

Comment: IMHO the issue is not related to the top-bit-set bytes, unless behind NFS there is a character-based protocol.

Comment: @HalosGhost its a shared facility, i did not set it up, i assume its a standard centos install, (other than that im not aware of any fancy customization of locale)

Comment: @enedil this is an enterprise grade NFS storage, (possibly provided by netap*)

Comment: @mike-m The latest edit of my answer should give you the explanation of `ls` output, and this would confirm a NFS-related issue.

Comment: @mike-m: Did you tried that command? What is the output?

Comment: @Learn  yes, i have, here is the output: `rl]$ rm -r mikeaâ\?\?cnt/`
`rm: cannot remove `mikeaâ??cnt/': No such file or directory` 
 see my comments on  3rd edit about the name

Comment: You say the directory is empty, but how empty is it? Does it still contain `.` and `..`? A few ideas, which might be worth trying: rename the directory to an all ASCII name, or reboot the client, or even get an administrator to rename it directly on the NFS server.

Comment: @kasperd  im not sure  whether it has `.` and `..` since it will not allow a `cd` or `ls` in  or on it,  rename wont work for the same reason `ls` `rm`  will not work (i tried rename earlier, but its not in my question, maybe i should add that output, ), i will talk to some priviledged admins and see how to proceed.

Comment: @mike-m Previously you said: "i can `cd` to it though and its empty", but the `ls` command you ran did not have the flags to display `.` and `..` if they existed.

Comment: @kasperd yes, at the start of the delete effort i could, but look at the question and about the 5th edit i mentioned the behavior had changed, and i could not `cd`.

Comment: As someone with very little experience with unix and linux, here's my idea: try renaming the directory to something without those symbols using `mv`. maybe you can delete it after that. Alternatively, you can try moving the directory to a deeper folder level (maybe with a wildcard) and then deleting the folder you've moved it to.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Thats actually a good idea, but i had tried that much earlier and it failed, and i had not included that info on the question, but i have added something on move now.

Comment: How important is rl? Is it a root directory that is required at all times, or can you, say, move everything else to a safe location, try to delete rl and then put it back?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs  rl is empty exept for the problematic dir inside it, so that is the catch, if i try to delete rl, it rm will attempt to delete the bad directory inside it, of course i can rename rl, and move it, but the corrupt dir inside it is the troublemaker, and eitherway no delete happens until the bad dir is gone, :(

Comment: I suspect the directory only exists in memory on the client and is long gone on the server. Have you tried umounting it and mounting it again? Have you tried rebooting the client? Is it visible on other clients?

Comment: Note that the `-f` option of `rm` will hide most errors, in particular if the directory does not exist or cannot be removed. Thus it is a bad idea to use it here, in order to get diagnostic messages.

Comment: @kasperd its  a live production shared facility, and i will not have a chance to meet the admins till 0800 tommorrow,  but the behavour is identical from two client machines accessing the same NFS space.

Comment: @mike-m It sounds like you've hit an NFS bug, probably in the NFS server. Either that or filesystem corruption on the server. I doubt you can really do anything else other than wait for the NFS server admin(s) to deal with it.

Comment: No inode? Yikes. Does `strace rm -r mike*` (or some other reliable targetting glob) show anything helpful?  From all reports, I think @derobert NFS theory is right.

Comment: Can you use SED to change its contents? Doesn't dirs have some metadata you can edit? Like vim 'dirname'?

Comment: This may not reveal any new information, but: please post the output of `strace -xx rmdir ./* | grep -e '-1 E'` and `strace -xx -e trace=file ls -li`, executed from the directory *containing* the problem directory.

Comment: Can you not delete the directory above it (`rm -R 'parentdirectory'`)? What error does this produce?

Comment: +1 for persistence! And for thorough documentation of everything you tried. We don't usually get to see what didn't work, but it's often very valuable to know.

Comment: Try deleting the filesystem, recreate it and restore your backup (assuming you have tested it) excluding the corrupt files / directories.

Comment: indelible.  the undeletable is something capable of being undeleted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following excerpt from [this essay](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html) potentially explains why that directory refuses to be deleted:

> NFSv4 requires that all filenames be exchanged using UTF-8 over the wire. The NFSv4 specification, RFC 3530, says that filenames should be UTF-8 encoded in section 1.4.3: “In a slight departure, file and directory names are encoded with UTF-8 to deal with the basics of internationalization.” The same text is also found in the newer NFS 4.1 RFC (RFC 5661) section 1.7.3. The current Linux NFS client simply passes filenames straight through, without any conversion from the current locale to and from UTF-8. Using non-UTF-8 filenames could be a real problem on a system using a remote NFSv4 system; any NFS server that follows the NFS specification is supposed to reject non-UTF-8 filenames. So if you want to ensure that your files can actually be stored from a Linux client to an NFS server, you must currently use UTF-8 filenames. In other words, although some people think that Linux doesn’t force a particular character encoding on filenames, in practice it already requires UTF-8 encoding for filenames in certain cases.
>
> UTF-8 is a longer-term approach. Systems have to support UTF-8 as well as the many older encodings, giving people time to switch to UTF-8. To use “UTF-8 everywhere”, all tools need to be updated to support UTF-8. Years ago, this was a big problem, but as of 2011 this is essentially a solved problem, and I think the trajectory is very clear for those few trailing systems.
>
> Not all byte sequences are legal UTF-8, and you don’t want to have to figure out how to display them. If the kernel enforces these restrictions, ensuring that only UTF-8 filenames are allowed, then there’s no problem... all the filenames will be legal UTF-8. Markus Kuhn’s utf8_check C function can quickly determine if a sequence is valid UTF-8.
>
> The filesystem should be requiring that filenames meet some standard, not because of some evil need to control people, but simply so that the names can always be displayed correctly at a later time. The lack of standards makes things harder for users, not easier. Yet the filesystem doesn’t force filenames to be UTF-8, so it can easily have garbage.

Comment: This seems  to echo the explanation from out local admins, i will mark this as the answer going by the admins explanation. See my final edit

Answer (score 19):

One way to delete files/direcories like this is by their inode-reference.

To find the inodes for elements in current dir:

```
ls -i
14813568 mikeaâcnt
```

To delete this:

```
find . -inum 14813568 -delete
```

Comment: please see 5th edit.

Comment: No, this does not delete files by their inode. This looks for a file name for the given inode, and then deletes the file by its name. It cannot help here, as an attempt was already made with the correct name (alongside other attempts with an incorrect name).

Comment: @Gilles - technically, it looks for an inode dentry and returns a filename, but I agree.

Comment: Maybe something like: mv 'file' $(echo 'file' | sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._-]/_/g')  I've stolen this from server fault but I'm on handy and could not get the url

Comment: @Nicolai not helping for me. Directory not empty message comes up.

Comment: Yeah, hah, funny story about this: The file I'm trying to delete has `?` as its inode reference. How do you delete it then?

Answer (score 7):

You should not use non-ASCII characters in the command line since as you could see, for some reason, they won't necessarily correspond to the filename (Unicode has various ways for expressing accented letters). Something like:

```
rm -rf mike*
```

should work since the filename is directly generated by the shell. But make sure there's only one match (do an `echo mike*` first to confirm).

Well, if `cd` works, then there's no reason why `rm` or `ls` should say `No such file or directory`, so that the problem may be at the file system level.

Note: Do not use `ls` to find whether a directory is empty, but `ls -a`.

The directory may still be used by another process (including if it's the cwd of some process). IMHO, that's why it still "exists" but can yield errors, e.g. with `ls`; `lsof` may give you some information, but with NFS, you need to find which machine uses it. Especially with NFS, this can yield strange errors. `ls -a` in the parent directory could show you `.nfs*` files/directories in some cases.

When you get:

```
$ ls
ls: cannot access mikeaâcnt: No such file or directory
mikeaâ??cnt
```

I suspect that the file still exists in the **directory table** due to NFS caching and/or because it is used by another process, but without associated information. When `ls` tries to get information on the file itself, it gets an error as the file itself no longer exists (it is only in the directory table), hence the displayed error. Then `ls` outputs the filename because it is in the directory table. The fact you have question marks in one case but not in the other case is due to a display bug of `ls` IMHO (unrelated to your problem).

Comment: i had tried a wildcard earlier, it did not work, and i failed to post that attempt in my question, i will update with the result

Comment: See my third edit. IMHO this is due to NFS (probably not corruption, but bad caching) and possibly the fact that another process is using the directory. In some cases, one needs to reboot everything (the server and the clients).

Comment: Maybe this could explain things, but i cant be sure since i  dont have the priviledges to take it down for tests. See the 5th edit.

Comment: @vinc17 Please do not use "EDIT" in your answer, because for new reader is doesn't make sense (there is already an edit history)

Comment: iv added some lsof output, not sure whether it can tell you anything tho,

Comment: Your `lsof` invocation is incorrect. You should do something like: `lsof | grep mike`

Comment: ok, iv corrected it,

Answer (score 3):

I have personally tested using `find`'s `-exec` directive:

```
$ mkdir -p mikeaâcnt
$ ls
mikeaâcnt
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -exec rm -rf {} +
$ ls
$
```

The folder was correctly created and correctly removed.

As pointed out by [@Igeorget](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147377/how-to-delete-this-undeletable-directory#comment238744_147378), there's an even simpler method if you have GNU `find`:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -delete
```

I also tested this command, and it functions correctly

Comment: And if you use GNU's find, there's a `-delete` option too.

Comment: Please see 3rd edit,

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem, I believe. I have seen the problem earlier with a filename of `☃`. `ls` in this case displayed the file as `â??`, but I was able to delete it with `rm ☃`.

This led me to the following way to convert the wrong name to the correct one:

First get the bytes of the filename:

```
$ ls --show-control-chars | xxd
0000000: 6d69 6b65 61c3 a2c2 81c2 8463 6e74 0a    mikea......cnt.
```

Then decode these bytes as UTF-8, to get the unicode codepoints, using the hexadecimal input of this website for example: http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder

```
U+006D LATIN SMALL LETTER M character
U+0069 LATIN SMALL LETTER I character
U+006B LATIN SMALL LETTER K character
U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E character
U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A character
U+00E2 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX character (&#x00E2;)
U+0081 <control> character (&#x0081;)
U+0084 <control> character (&#x0084;)
U+0063 LATIN SMALL LETTER C character
U+006E LATIN SMALL LETTER N character
U+0074 LATIN SMALL LETTER T character
```

Notice these are all below the byte boundary. We obtain the following bytes:

```
6D 69 6B 65 61 E2 81 84 63 6E 74
```

If we treat this sequence at UTF-8 we get:

```
U+006D LATIN SMALL LETTER M character
U+0069 LATIN SMALL LETTER I character
U+006B LATIN SMALL LETTER K character
U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E character
U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A character
U+2044 FRACTION SLASH character (&#x2044;)
U+0063 LATIN SMALL LETTER C character
U+006E LATIN SMALL LETTER N character
U+0074 LATIN SMALL LETTER T character
```

And thus your filename is: `mikea⁄cnt`, with a fraction slash instead of a normal forward one. You may now pass this name to `rmdir`.

Comment: Thats  ingenious,  if i meet this again,  il keep this in mind. good one. +1

Answer (score 1):

For those who use a NetApp for the NFS3 volume, which is mounted on a linux machine:

[https://kb.netapp.com/Advice_and_Troubleshooting/Data_Storage_Software/ONTAP_OS/containing_0x80_(octal__0200)_characterin_the_file_name（UTF-8）._The_file_can_not_be_deleted](https://kb.netapp.com/Advice_and_Troubleshooting/Data_Storage_Software/ONTAP_OS/containing_0x80_(octal__0200)_characterin_the_file_name%EF%BC%88UTF-8%EF%BC%89._The_file_can_not_be_deleted)

```
cluster1::> set -privilege advanced

cluster1::*> vserver nfs modify -vserver <SVM_NAME> -v3-search-unconverted-filename enabled

cluster1::*> set -privilege admin
```

After I ran the command all non ASCII files were easily removed with the `rm -rf <folder>` command.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the correct hex code of file / folder name (using whatever method one sees fit, I may choose `ls --show-control-chars | xxd`), some special construct should be used to address such characters when running under bash:

```
rmdir $'mikea\xc3\xa2\xc2\x81\xc2\x84cnt'
```

Otherwise backslashes are treated as vanilla backslash.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit (8th edit)

Comment: @mike-m Of course that doesn't exist, because `ls` includes newline in output data and the "cnt" is duplicated. Maybe you can try directly copy and paste the line in my answer and see if it's effective?

Comment: Nope, still  this: ``` rl]$ rmdir $'mikea\xc3\xa2\xc2\x81\xc2\x84cnt' 
rmdir: failed to remove `mikeaâ\302\201\302\204cnt': No such file or directory```

Comment: In that case it is quite likely a combination of NFS problem and the locale preventing most system utilities to pass incorrect non-UTF8 bytes. And it looks like the inode removal has worsened the situation. For now, the only way I can think of is setting your system to a locale-free environment (use "C" locale for `LC_*` and `LANG` env variables), and mount NFS without any character set options

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `rm -rf ./mikeaâcnt` or `rm -rf "./mikeaâcnt"` or an absolute path? Also instead of `rm`, try `rmdir ./mikeaâcnt`.

Comment: part of the problem is that the characters in  `mikeaâcnt` seem not to be the filename,  but what  `ls`  displays, see  the 3rd edit

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get the inode of that file with `stat`:

```
stat mike*
```

That should give you the inode number (and other data), and then you could try to delete it.

Comment: iv added an edit with `stat` behavour,

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. Do you have Gnome, KDE or some kind of Xwindow DM?. If you do open your file broser and remove the file from there.

It should work.

I would like to see a solution from the command line, but in my case and after losing a lot of time trying to figure out how to remove it from the command line I found that it was as simple as removing any other file from nautilus or any other file explorer (truth is I have only tried with nautilus).