# Deleting ghost files with non-ASCII characters

Tags: files, osx, filenames, rm, unicode

I have some weird files and folders in my trash on Mac OS X. After I "empty" the trash, the files still remain. I attempted to manually delete the files:

```
$ cd /Volumes/VOLUME/.Trashes/501/foldertobedeleted
$ rm -rf * # there's nothing I need here
[...]
rm: somanyfolders: Directory not empty
```

Weird, right? So I track down the files:

```
$ ls /Volumes/VOLUME/.Trashes/501/foldertobedeleted/somanyfolders
Φύλλο κόντακτ.mkpdf           Προσαρμογή σε 3x5.mkpdf
Περικοπή σε 3x5.mkpdf          Προσαρμογή σε 4x6.mkpdf
Περικοπή σε 4x6.mkpdf          Προσαρμογή σε 5x7.mkpdf
Περικοπή σε 5x7.mkpdf          Προσαρμογή σε 8x10.mkpdf
Περικοπή σε 8x10.mkpdf
```

Well, that's annoying. These files didn't even show up in Finder! Well, let's just delete them:

```
$ cd /Volumes/VOLUME/.Trashes/501/foldertobedeleted/somanyfolders
$ rm *
rm: Φύλλο κόντακτ.mkpdf: No such file or directory
rm: Περικοπή σε 3x5.mkpdf: No such file or directory
rm: Περικοπή σε 4x6.mkpdf: No such file or directory
rm: Περικοπή σε 5x7.mkpdf: No such file or directory
rm: Περικοπή σε 8x10.mkpdf: No such file or directory
rm: Προσαρμογή σε 3x5.mkpdf: No such file or directory
rm: Προσαρμογή σε 4x6.mkpdf: No such file or directory
rm: Προσαρμογή σε 5x7.mkpdf: No such file or directory
rm: Προσαρμογή σε 8x10.mkpdf: No such file or directory
```

What? `ls` showed all the files though! How can I delete these files?

Comment: Isn't this something useful:[how-to-delete-this-undeletable-directory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147377/how-to-delete-this-undeletable-directory?rq=1)

Comment: @somethingSomething As far as I can see, the OP of the question was unable to resolve their issue, they asked an administrator for help with deleting the concerned files.

Comment: Hope thats ok, I just skimmed the post and thought there might be some helpful information there, I don't know much about it myself. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to OSX so this is a wild guess... but you can try other techniques to delete files, rather than relying on the shell's globbing to match.  Try:

```
find . -not -type d -print -delete
```

or even

```
find . -not -type d -print | perl -nle 'print; unlink'
```