# Totally unreadable and inaccessible dir?

Tags: mount, directory, samba, fstab

I am getting this output from `ls -a` for a specific dir`

```
d??????????  ? ?        ?           ?             ? dmsnl857-vm
```

This was a mount dir according to my `/etc/fstab`

```
//192.168.33.55/DMS /home/pkaramol/Workspace/servers/dmsnl857-vm/ cifs credentials=/home/pkaramol/.smb857cred,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

I am unable to perform **any** action on it any more, including deleting it via the `inode` as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147385/136100).

Even as `root`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a filesystem failure, umount, remount. If it fail again, try a fsck/chkdisk in host 192.168.33.55.

Comment: Regardless of what `fstab` says, is it actually mounted? Does it look like the same if you do mount or unmount it? Any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Did you get any error messages with that? That looks consistent with
having only read permission to the containing directory (`r` but no `x`), that would make the `stat` on the file fail, leaving `ls` unable to show the owner, size, or permissions:

```
$ mkdir foo foo/test; chmod -x foo; ls -l foo
ls: cannot access 'foo/test': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? test/
```

(Of course you could have a broken filesystem instead, but you'd probably get some errors in that case too.)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely something went wrong with your login credentials for the network drive (the password changed or the account got suspended).

Try to force the unmount:

```
umount -f -t cifs /home/pkaramol/Workspace/servers/dmsnl857-vm/
```

If you are having trouble dismounting a drive, make sure that you don't have a console open somewhere where the current working directory (CWD) on the drive which you are trying to dismount, or have a file open in an editor or player somewhere or such.

Reference:

- https://oracletechdba.blogspot.com/2017/06/umount-lsof-warning-cant-stat-cifs-file.html