# File with name ':'

Tags: files, filesystems, cifs

**EDIT**
I've just found out that the file system on which this does not work appears to be `cifs`. So this is probably a file system issue.

**FINAL EDIT**
With the help of our system admin, I could log onto the disk server. There, the command `rm :` worked. It's kind of annoying to require help from someone for such a task and this does not really answer the question. I still have no idea what was going on.

A related post that I found during my last searches and that I found relevant :
[How to delete this undeletable directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147377/how-to-delete-this-undeletable-directory)

---

I accidentally created a file named `:` and I wish to delete it.
However, the shell (`bash`) has a strange behavior, so I can't seem to manipulate the file. I could find its inode, but can't find what to do next.
Could anyone help ? Thanks !

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
[snip]
$ ls -l 
[snip]
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  41086 Oct  5 13:50 :
$ rm :
rm: cannot remove ':': No such file or directory
$ rm -iv *
rm: remove regular file ':'? y
rm: cannot remove ':': No such file or directory
rm: remove regular file 'a.out'? ^C
$ touch :
$ ls -l 
[snip]
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user      0 Oct  5 14:13 :
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user      0 Oct  5 14:13 :
$ rm : ; ls -l
[snip]
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  41086 Oct  5 13:50 :
$ stat -c '%n %i' *
: 17915935
[snip]
```

Comment: Can you add the output of command `grep $(whoami) /etc/passwd ; bash --version` to the topic?

Comment: What is the output of `LC_ALL=C ls`? If you're getting two files with the same name after a `touch`, then I'd guess either one of them _isn't_ named as it appears, or there is file system corruption. Given your symptoms, the latter seems a bit more likely (in which case a `fsck` in single-user mode may be a good idea)

Comment: your copy show file being trucated, also you mention cifs, maybe you can delete on server (if it is a distant cifs).

Answer (score 1):

looks like macOS (`:`) was used as file delimitor as those time.

try

```
find . -inum 17915935 -print
```

If there is only one

```
find . -inum 17915935 -delete
```

Comment: It does not work. There is only one file with inode `17915935` but `find . -inum 17915935 -delete` gives the result `find: cannot delete './:': No such file or directory`. Thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: This is what caused me to write my answer -- the reason this isn't working is I believe find is calling `rm -f ./:` which spawns a new shell or something.

Comment: @djsmiley2k It does not.

Answer (score 0):

If all the other suggestions fail, move all other contents of the directory out of the way and delete the directory itself from its parent directory using `rm -rf directory_name`.

Comment: I have tried this, but it does not work. I have renamed the old directory and work now without the spurious file. But it is still there in a dead directory waiting for a proper death. Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

Try

`rm -rf "./\:"`

The `\` will escape the `:` from trying to do other things such as spawning a new shell, the `./` tells bash that you wish to do something to a file in the current directory.

Also, `rm -rf "./:"` and `rm -rf "\:"` may work depending on where the file has been created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, none of these solutions worked for me...

Comment: I would really really really advise against that. **Never** issue `-f` to any command when you are not sure what is going on, especially `rm` and even more with `-r`. In fact, I would recommend you to use `rm -i "./\:"` instead.

Answer (score -3):

could you please try

```
rm -f :
```

it's working for me

Comment: `rm -f :` does not remove the file.

Comment: are you getting any error @Tom-Tom